# Character ä is represented in different Char Codes in the same string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a on web uploaded File Name "Schränke Wintsch.pdf".
The file Name is saved in a XML file like so:

```
<File>Schra?nke Wintsch.pdf</File>
```

If I debug this in c# and maunally add an ä, then it is saved correctly.

```
<File>Schra?nke Wintsch-ä.pdf</File>
```

OK I know it is an Encoding Problem.
But why is the same ä character represented with different char codes(example on Img 2)?

[image: Img 1]

[image: Img 2]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thisi is the string fileName = "Schränke Wintsch-ä.pdf"; With different ä-s

Answer (score 2):

The original XML that you have is using the [Unicode 'COMBINING DIAERESIS' code](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm) (int value 776) to use two characters to represent`ä`.

(Note how the combining character has been displayed as `?` in the `<File>Schra?nke Wintsch.pdf</File>` image in your post.)

The 776 code says to put the double-dots above the previous character (an `a`).

However, where you typed in the `ä` it has been stored as the unicode character with code 228.

The question you need to answer is: Why is the original source XML using the "Combining Diaeresis" character rather than the more usual `ä`? (Without knowing the origin of the XML file, we cannot answer that question.)

Incidentally, you can "normalise" those sorts of characters by using [`string.Normalize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2), as demonstrated by the following program:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            char[] a = {(char)97, (char)776};
            string s = new string(a);

            Console.WriteLine(s + " -> " + s.Length); // Prints a¨ -> 2

            var t = s.Normalize();
            Console.WriteLine(t + " -> " + t.Length); // Prints ä -> 1
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the length of `s` is 2, but the length of `t` is only 1 (and it contains the single character `ä`).

So you might be able to improve things by using `string.Normalize()` to normalise these unexpected characters.

Answer (score 2):

XML defines the encoding used within the document using the header. It will look something like this.. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9" ?>`.

If you append the string make sure to use the same encoding to avoid a mismatch.

Test appending the char bytes and see if that helps.

```
var en = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");

en.GetString(Encoding.GetBytes("ä"));
```

Answer (score 0):

string.Normalize()  ist the working solution for the string "Schränke Wintsch-ä.pdf". So it ist correctly saved as Schränke Wintsch-ä.pdf